# .net c# - Context Class Removes its constructor while scaffolding

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am doing project in .net core api. Whenever I used to scaffold to sync with database, constructor created in context class disappears after scaffolding. What to do and why it is happening ?

Comment: Is the DbContext generated as a partial class? If so then create a second file also for `partial class DbContext { ... }` and add the constructor in there.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? @Peter B

Comment: See **https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3406**. In general, **a [Partial Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)** is a class that can consist of 2 or more code files. Partial Files that are generated should not be modified by you (because changes you make will be lost). The other partial file(s) can be maintained manually, and together as a whole they define **one class**.

Comment: What @PeterB said. Never change files created by a generator directly. Partial classes were introduced for that exact reason

Comment: thanx @PeterB...it works

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify the autogenerated classes. You can see the autogenerated designer classes when you add a webform or winform in application for your reference that how partial claases are implemented. Its always recommended that you should modify the proper class. Partial classes are like the same class but have multiple definitions so that you can seggregate the implementation and define a logical grouping. Another example is multiple developers can work paralallry work of this class.

You can refer the below doc for reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods